# can't update spyder to 4.0.0b2

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to update Spyder to version 4.0.0b2 but I'm getting an error. I don't have a lot of experience with cmd or anaconda prompt, so I don't understand the problem. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I agree with Jonathan's answer below: you need to uninstall your current spyder and spyder-kernels packages in order to install our beta ones. However, if you're not an experienced programmer, my recommendation is to stay with our current stable version and wait until the final version of Spyder 4 is released (in a few months). Spyder 4 is still moving very rapidly and you'll find a lot of bugs on it, so it's not yet ready for general usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not on MS Windows but I see several things in your screenshot

1. You are on base environment
2. You already have `spyder 3.3.3` and that means that you have to use `conda update spyder` or uninstall it and then install it with your command `conda install -c spyder-ide spyder=4.0.0b2`
3. The same with all remaining packages mentioned there (preferably one by one since some may disappear like the kernel one when you uninstall spyder 3.3.3)
4. If you see that Anaconda cannot find the package in your current channels, try via proposed channels on [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo) like `conda search --override-channels --channel URL/PACKAGE`

Hope it helps (: